# ScrollTop() function, scroll time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

When function is called, the page scrolls up to the top, but I need to wait for as long as the animate time is set to, to be able to scroll down again. for example if I say

`$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);`

It makes me wait for a while to be able to scroll down again, but if I write

`$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 10);`

It scrolls up a lot faster, but I will be able to immediately scroll down again! How can I use `800` (so the animate acts cooler) but avoid waiting for scrolling down again?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.goToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.goToTop').fadeOut();
    }
    $('#goToTop').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You could add a setTimeout(func() { },800) that would be invoked after 800ms to do whatever you wanted at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can stop any ongoing animation using the following code .

```
$( 'html,body' ).stop();
```

edit: the animation has to stop only if the scroll was triggered by a human. Heres a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sjp3xngo/4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a `setTimeout` function inside the callback function of `.animate()` (the one which scrolls the window to top) in order to scroll down BACK to its earlier position. Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/w9a6h0h0/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#goToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#goToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    var duration_ms = 800;
    $('#goToTop').click(function () {
        var last_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, duration_ms, function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
                 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: last_scroll }, duration_ms);
           }, duration_ms);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#goToTop{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
  a
  b
  c
  d
  q
  w
  e
  r
  t
  y
  u
  i
  o
  p
  a
  s
  d
  f
  g
  h
  j
  k
  l
  z
  x
  c
  v
  b
  n
  m
  <span id="goToTop">go to top</span>
</pre>
```